# How to mount Ubuntu server to windows network drive?

Tags: windows-7, vmware, network-shares, mount

I am using windows 7 client and the latest version of ubuntu server installed inside vmware workstation.

Ubuntu server is a fresh install with just openssh server as the only program I installed in it via apt get so far.

I would like to get access to the Ubuntu server file system through a mapped drive on windows. When I go to Computer >> Map Network Drive and enter:

```
\\192.168.163.129\home\tk
```

It errors out saying `windows cannot access: \\192.168.163.129\home\tk.`

Is there anything I have to install to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want samba not samba4, but it should work fine anyway; run 'smbpasswd -a USERNAME' and enter a password for your user. Samba keeps it's own password store that can be synced with the linux password (and last I checked the default in ubuntu is to turn on syncing) but you have to set the initial password with 'smbpasswd -a'.

Also, edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and uncomment the homes section (should be near the bottom). Leave the other settings to default.

It should look something like:

[home]
  browseable = no
  valid user = %s

(that is off the top of my head; probably best to not just copy paste in to your config, but those are the 2 directives samba will usually need for homes)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using Samba. I haven't set it up myself, but I know that it implements the same protocol that Windows normally uses to communicate with network drives. Ubuntu 12.04 has it as a package under the name `samba`, so just run `sudo apt-get install samba`.

Comment: I install samba4 on the server and tried to map the network drive again and got the same error. Did I have to do anything else after installing samba?

Comment: so after install samba not samba4 I do get a password prompt. But when I type my password which is correct it says network password is incorrect.

Comment: Try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/91797/windows7-the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct-when-the-password-is

Comment: Those fixes listed are not relevant on an recent version of samba. You shouldn't need to change anything on the windows side, source: i'm running samba 3 and 4 against windows 7/8 clients and they still work fine after slowly upgrading from xp->vista->onwards